# java.sql.SQLException: You cannot rollback with autocommit set

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have a problem with my project. The problem occurs when I make a connection to the database with a library.

This library has the following code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try {
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(this.sqlIniBD);
    stmt.setString(1, id);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    if (this.tavi.activo()) this.tavi.escribir(toString(), "No se ha podido insertar la fila inicial para las claves de encriptacion (" + id + "). Posiblemente ya existe: " + t);
}
```

I want to ask you, if there is any possibility to put `autoCommit(false)`, in my `standalone.xml`. Maybe this is weird or stupid. This is the datasource for example:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/xxx" pool-name="xxx" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@oradag.cm.es:1524:oradag1</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <connection-property name="autoCommit">
        <!-- not working -->false 
    </connection-property>
    <driver>ojdbc7.jar</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>xxx</user-name>
        <password>xxx</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

Any ideas??? I can't modify the library, I don't have the code.

So my only hope resides in the `standalone.xml`.

Comment: You are working in JBoss or WildFly or something of the sort?

Comment: 14:58:12,349 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) iniciando

Comment: Thats exactly mi jboss version

Comment: Where is the stacktrace with all the exception info? can you attach?

Comment: Sure... its here...

Comment: ####[1.-es.cm.arq.psv.base.GProcesosException: (COD:5) Error ejecutando accion (es.cm.pf.ficheros.subprocesos.PFIsef,-1)
3.-java.sql.SQLException: You cannot rollback with autocommit set!
java.sql.SQLException: You cannot rollback with autocommit set!

Comment: Your program is rolling back because of an error or you are doing it intentionally? I think you have to investigate what error triggers the rollback action.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40787966/edit) your question and include the relevant strack trace **inside** the question? Also mention at what point exactly the error occurs. That stack trace is information that should be in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: Your code explicitly sets `con.setAutoCommit(true)`, so the answer is no, not without proxying the connection and ignoring `setAutoCommit`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally , the solution was to pick the code inside the jar, and make a new java project. Change the variable to setAutoCommit(false), and recompile again the project, with export like a jar. So, finally i get my new jar with the value changed in my variable.

A weird solution, but was solved the problem.  I used a decompiler of course, to make possible this solution

Thank you all